# "Have been born" vs. "are born" vs. "were born"

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

> We are native to this country. We have been born here to serve it.

Is the use of "have been" acceptable here? I think the simple past *were* is more appropriate.

Also, what about:

> We are native to this country. We **are born** here to serve it

Does that sound grammatical?

Comment: Maybe just me, but I think *have been born here* is slightly odd. It's a bit like the difference between *"I have been put here to serve you"* and *"I am here to serve you"*. If you *have been [verbed]* anything, the implication is usually that somebody else (God, here?) caused that to happen. At least with *I am / We are here*, it's left open as to whether you've done it *by your own choice*. Which in OP's example could be interpreted as meaning *having grown up and come to understand the concept of nationality, I **choose** to serve my country.*

Comment: This is a good question for our sister site, ELL, [English Language learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I'm afraid that some users on this site would consider your grammar based question a bit too basic.

Comment: An idiom you may have confused this with is "born to serve", not "born here to serve"

Answer (score 3):

Both *We have been born here to serve it* and *We were born here to serve it* are grammatical. The difference is one of tone and emphasis, and depends on the occasion on which each is used and on what has been said previously. Very generally, the first might be used rhetorically in a speech, where the speaker wants to relate the birth of those addressed to the present moment. The second is more likely to occur in ordinary conversation, assuming such a thing would be said at all in ordinary conversation.

*We are born here to serve it* applies, in the speaker's view, to everyone at all times.